# How To Use COALESCE() to Add Additional Characters

Tags: sql, coalesce

I have the following syntax on my SELECT Statement:

```
CONCAT(first_name, " ", COALESCE(middle_initial), " ", last_name) AS full_name
```

Obviously, what I get is the following:

```
For first_name='John' and middle_initial='A.' and last_name='Smith' 
I get 'John A. Smith'
```

That is fine and is the desired result.

But I get an extra space for the following data (which I clearly understand why):

```
For first_name='John' and middle_initial='' and last_name='Smith' 
I get 'John  Smith'
```

Is there a way with `COALESCE()` to append " " if the condition returns a non-null value?

Thank you.

Comment: If your `middle_initial` is an empty string, it's not necessarily `NULL`.  Some RDBMS treat `''` and `NULL` as the same thing, some don't.  Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: MySQL with Table and Column Collation "utf8_general_ci"

Comment: Thanks @Dems -- I am not married to COALSCE() - it just seemed to get me close to what I was attempting to do. Is there a different way to do this -- say using IF()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When middle_initial has '', you would want to:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', 
   CASE
      WHEN middle_initial is null OR middle_initial = '' then ''
      ELSE CONCAT(middle_initial, ' ')
   END
   , last_name) AS full_name
```

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bdd1/7/0)

`COALESCE` is used for checking `NULL` values, not handling empty strings, ''

Comment: but it middle_initial is the empty string this will append an extra space

Comment: If you have '' and not just null values, I will update my answer to address that.  `COALESCE` is responsible for handling NULL values

Comment: @H.Ferrence Yes it is - I had to edit my original answer when the empty string had to be taken into account, and using a `CASE` is my preferred way to accommodate the OP's question.

Comment: In this answer the result returned is zero (0)

Answer (score 2):

```
select concat(first_name , ' ' , 
     case when middle_initial is null then ''
          when middle_initial = '' then ''
          else concat(middle_initial, ' ') end ,
     last_name)
```

this query asumes that first_name and last_name are not null nor empty string, in that case you can apply same logic to that fields

Comment: In this answer the result returned is zero (0)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT rtrim(Coalesce(first_name + ' ','') 
        + Coalesce(nullif(middle_name,'') + ' ', '') 
        + Coalesce(nullif(last_name,'') + ' ', ''))
FROM @table


SELECT rtrim(Coalesce('John' + ' ','') 
        + Coalesce(nullif('A.','') + ' ', '') 
        + Coalesce(nullif('Smith','') + ' ', ''))

SELECT rtrim(Coalesce('John' + ' ','') 
        + Coalesce(nullif('','') + ' ', '') 
        + Coalesce(nullif('Smith','') + ' ', ''))
```

Comment: why your anwser has 'constants' instead of fields_names??

Comment: yes OP can replace constants with column names, this is sample query with different data to show how it can achieved.

Comment: i am glad that you did the replace becouse may be dificult to guess where to replace in `nullif('','')` for example

Comment: That returns a zero (0) for the middle initial even after I corrected the SQL syntax to `middle_initial` not `middle_name`

Answer (score 1):

I think best way is to do it like this. You can use such a constraction for any number of fields, variables and so on. Also it will correctly show you `John` or `John A.`

```
declare @Temp_Table table (first_name nvarchar(128), middle_initial nvarchar(128), last_name nvarchar(128))

insert into @Temp_Table
select 'John', null, 'Smith' union all
select 'John', 'A.', 'Smith' union all
select 'John', 'A.', null union all
select 'John', null, null

select
    *,
    stuff
    (
        isnull(' ' + nullif(first_name, ''), '') +
        isnull(' ' + nullif(middle_initial, ''), '') +
        isnull(' ' + nullif(last_name, ''), ''),
        1, 1, ''
    )
from @Temp_Table
```

Comment: I got `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'isnull'`

Comment: wait a sec i'll create you MySQL example

Comment: Ok, thanks @RomanPekar -- but I got the selected answer above to work for me and I need to move on.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b002/20 try this. Actually I think that answer above is example of bad code, it's not reusable. My advice is to get piece of code that can be easily usable in the future in other cases. But it's your choice of course.